# From which $n$ is this sequence monotone?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

My professor asked this question in an exam and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Given the sequence $a_n=\dfrac{(3n+3)^2}{(2n-10)^2}$, from which $n$ is this sequence monotone?

I'm not sure I understand what he means. I can determine that the sequence is monotone like this:$$a_n=\left (\frac{3n+3}{2n-10}\right )^2=\left (\frac{3}{2}\frac{(n-5)+18}{n-5}\right )^2=\left (\frac{3}{2}\frac{(n-5)}{(n-5)}+\frac{18}{n-5}\right )^2.$$Looking at $\dfrac{18}{n-5}$ we can determine that the limit of the number we add to the rest of the equation is $0$ so $a_n$ is monotonically increasing to a limit $\dfrac{9}{4}$.

But how do I find the $n$ from which the the sequence is monotone? Is it from the vertical asymptote at $n=5$ where $(2n-10)^2$ is $0$?

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: A sequence in $X$ is a function from $\mathbb{N} \to X$ . Be careful to define a function, first task is to make sure whether the function is well defined or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence only makes sense for $n>5$. Then as both factors of the fraction are positive, you can ignore the squares. Next,

$$\frac{3n+3}{2n-10}=\frac32\left(1+\frac{6}{n-5}\right)$$ is decreasing.

Comment: Ah I see, the sequence can not have undefined terms. So his question was more about from what $n$ do we make sense of the sequence and from that it'll be monotone (decreasing, as you pointed out).

Comment: @Benjamin: I don't like this exercise. A sequence is deemed to start at $n=0$ or $n=1$ (depending on your definition of naturals), and have all terms defined. Otherwise it is not really a sequence. Review the exact definition in your course.